# Subdomain Management Script

Tags: subdomain, automation

Hai all,

I would like to learn the basics of server management. I have been told that there are tools to automate creation and activation of subdomains. Do you know any? Guess they will be cgi, any php scripts out there too?

Thank you

Comment: What are you referring to by subdomain?  Is this web server related, DNS, Active Directory, naval warfare?

Comment: I am talking about http://subdomain.domain.com

Comment: Uh, ok.  http://r00tshell.com/dns-control/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are referring to web domains in a LAMP environment, I have found **VirtualMin** to be very helpful for this.  They have both a paid and a free version.

There is a similar product called **cpanel** that you might want to look into as well.